# Restoring point when tangling current block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When I do

```
C-u C-c C-v t
```

to tangle the code block at point, my point moves to the head of the code block. How can I prevent that point movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to update to org 9.1.6. There they have moved the `save-excursion` to the beginning of `org-babel-tangle`.

By the way they use the wrong sequence `(save-restriction (save-excursion ...))`. Looks like that has historical reasons. Don't know what funny consequences that may have with `org-babel-tangle`. I think it would be worth a bug report.

If you want to keep an older version of `org-mode` you could put a `save-excursion` around `org-babel-tangle` via `:around` advice.
That looks like:

```el
(defun my-org-wrap-org-babel-tangle-in-save-excursion (oldfun &rest args)
"Put `save-excursion` around (org-babel-tangle (ARGS))."
  (save-excursion (apply oldfun args)))

(advice-add 'org-babel-tangle :around #'my-org-wrap-org-babel-tangle-in-save-excursion)
```